# Google Appengine & google Apps - mapping www.mydomain.com to my-app-id.appspot.com

Tags: google-app-engine

This must have been discussed number of times.. but honestly i did so
much googling around but it is impossible find a proper answer.

First i built an app using appengine. Then I went to Versions tab in my appengine and
tried to Add domain, which led me to buy the domain using google apps.
Once I bought it, i'm lost totally. How do I map my appengine
application to www.mydomain.com. I'm not asking about naked domain (http://mydomain.com).
that is the least of my problem.

I can see myapp.appspot.com as a service under google apps account.
But, how do I map it to www.mydomain.com? Currently it is getting mapped a "google sites" generated  page.

Please advice.

Answer (score 7):

Not having bought a domain through Google, I don't know if they provide DNS configuration. But what you need to do is to configure the DNS for your domain, so that it has a `CNAME` entry for the subdomain(s) you want to point to your application. It would look something like this:

```
Subdomain | Type  | Data
www       | CNAME | ghs.google.com.
```

Then, in the App Engine part of the Google Apps administration for your domain, you would click "Add new URL" and put "www" in the text box and press "Add".

Comment: Hi Blixt! This works for me. :) This was the only missing part at my end. I added WWW CNAME and now I am happy.

Answer (score 5):

The details on how to set it up is here

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/domains.html

If you want it to map to www. then put 'www' where they have 'my-app-id' in the last image.

Answer (score 0):

A quick guide to domain name setup on Google App Engine:
http://aralbalkan.com/1466

Are you looking for this.

Comment: I can't get this link to load