# google appspot application on custom domain?

Tags: google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Appengine & google Apps - mapping www.mydomain.com to my-app-id.appspot.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185335/google-appengine-google-apps-mapping-www-mydomain-com-to-my-app-id-appspot-co)

I already own a custom domain for example www.onlinecourse.com, and I already have an application running on google infrastructure or google app engine with www.onlinecourse.appspot.com (just for example).

What I want is when user try to access www.onlinecourse.com, my application that is running at www.onlinecourse.appspot.com should open up without URL redirection.

I was completely fooled by this statement from google app engine.

**"You can serve your app from your own domain name (such as http://www.example.com/) using Google Apps. Or, you can serve your app using a free name on the appspot.com domain. You can share your application with the world, or limit access to members of your organization."**

I thought www.onlinecourse.com would completely replaces the www.onlinecourse.appspot.com

Answer (score 5):

To just add a custom domain, just follow the instructions here:
http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/domains.html

And once that works, you can put a check in your code to forward anyone landing on the appspot.com domain to your domain: (example in python)

```
def get(self):
  if self.request.host.endswith('appspot.com'):
    return self.redirect('www.jaavuu.com', True)
  # ... your code ...
```

Comment: will the user's browser show http://example.appspot.com or will it show http://www.example.com? I have the same question for a java app I'm developing.

Comment: It will show www.example.com, since you can't map a naked domain (example.com) to Google App Engine.  But you can use any subdomain of that domain, so you could even map *.example.com and have any subdomain of example.com (including www) map to the same app.  (Note that you must have a DNS server that can do wildcard requests.)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question should be just this url

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/domains.html

which Amir has already pointed out.

But let me add some stuff. Firstly this is not a programming question. Second, nonetheless here's my answer.

Google uses Google Apps to manage its domains. Google Apps is something companies sign up for when they want to use gmail on mail@companydomain.com. Using Google Apps just for domain name mapping is a bit redundant, especially if you don't want any of the other stuff. But since you can disable the email, chat and other stuff, and since it is free, there is no reason , why you shouldn't sign up for Google Apps. First goto. http://www.google.com/a and sign up for the standard edition of google apps. Use a cname/meta tag/html file to verify your domain name. Once you have done that, you can add the domain name you want to use for your appspot hosted GAE app(eg. if you own the domain mydomain.com, you should map www.mydomain.com). You can redirect mydomain.com to www.domain.com using one of the n number of 301 redirect methods. I hear Google provides some IPs you can point your A names to.

Tutorial link:
http://aralbalkan.com/1466

In the tutorial, Mr. Balkan uses dynds as an example, which might not do the thing for you(it's not free). As I said before, your registrar might have enough DNS options. Else you can go for something like http://geoscaling.com (free 10 domains). The rest of the stuff should be the same.

(I guess you already have something to manage your DNS, for eg, Your domain name registrar generally gives you some amount of DNS control. Go into your domain's DNS settings and change the CNAME when required. If you can ftp to your domain's hosting, you will be able to use the meta tag or html file option to verify your domain. There are plenty of tutorials for Google Apps out there. If you are unsure, post a comment and I will expand the post)

After you are through, your www.onlinecourses.com should be what the user sees.

Comment: Just FYI, your first link you posted is broken.

Comment: @jmort253 corrected. It was the same as Amir's link.