# Forward appspot domain to my domain

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is there an easy way to forward my appspot domain to my domain.  Basically redirect myappid.appspot.com to myappid.com.  If people somehow find the appspot domain I don't want them using it.

I am already showing the same application at both domains.  I just don't want users to be able to use the application at myappid.appspot.com.

Comment: This has been discussed before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785934/google-appspot-application-on-custom-domain?rq=1

Comment: @Romin - he is asking the exact opposite.

Comment: Oops. I am sorry .. did not read it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so the answer is here to easily find.  I added the code below to a filter that runs on every page request.

```
if(((HttpServletRequest) req).getServerName().contains("appspot.com")){
            ((HttpServletResponse) resp).sendRedirect("http://"+((HttpServletRequest) req).getServerName().replace("myappid.appspot.com", "myappid.com") +  ((HttpServletRequest) req).getRequestURI());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a Servlet Filter to redirect. This thread gives you the details: [How to use a servlet filter in Java to change an incoming servlet request url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url)